# Python - For-Loop through all and then print?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, printing

So this is the code im providing and the description is below :)

```
r = s.get(Url)
names = soup(r.text, 'html.parser')
findName = names.find('div', {'class':'nameslist'})

 if (r.status_code == 200): 


    for name in names.find_all('option'):

            global nameID

            if myName == foundName:
                nameID = size.get('value')
                print('Profile-1 Found name')
                break

            else:
                print('Did not find name')


    if (findName != None):
        notepresent = True
        print('There is a value')
    else:
        global addtonotes
        notepresent = False
        addtonotes = {'id': nameID}
        add2notes(addtonotes)
```

***Output***

```
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Profile-1 Found name
```

What I want is that it should not say "Did not find name" until it has looped all the names through the loop and THEN say it did not find any names.
But what it does now is that it loops for each names one by one until it finds the name and then I used break to dont search for other names anymore since its not needed.

So the question is how can I turn it so it will say Did not find names when it has looped for every name and then say Did not find names after it has been looped through all names?

EDIT:

So whenever it found the Name it will go to `addtonotes = {'id': nameID}` and then it will be added to *addtonotes* but it dont find then there will be a traceback saying:

```
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Did not find name
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Test.py", line 153
     addtonotes = {'id': nameID}
NameError: name 'nameID' is not defined
```

So what I also want is that when its not finding any names then it should just use Sys.exit() but I can't really do it in the else statement now because it will sys.exit by the first loop...

I hope someone understand the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to set `nameID` to an empty value *before* the loop:

```
nameID = None
for name in names.find_all('option'):
    if myName == foundName:
        nameID = size.get('value')
        print('Profile-1 Found name')
        break

if nameID is None:
    print('Did not find name')
```

However, the Python `for` loop actually has dedicated syntax for this case; you can add an `else:` block to a `for` loop. It is only executed when the `for` loop *completes*, i.e. when there was no `break` to end the loop early:

```
for name in names.find_all('option'):
    if myName == foundName:
        nameID = size.get('value')
        print('Profile-1 Found name')
        break
else:
    print('Did not find name')
```

Comment: Oh. It helped abit but however whats happening now is that it says it finds name but then also says that it is not found. Output will say ```Profile-1 Found name  -  Did not find name``` but that was for the second edit you did.

Comment: @WeInThis: the code I posted can't print both; either `Profile-1 Found name` is printed and the `break` is executed, *or* the `else` block is reached. It can't do both, because of the `break`.

Comment: Oh okey. Well I did try the first solution and seems to get the result I wanted even without the break :) I think I can mark this as a solved. Im not sure yet but I will test around and see. So far so good! :)

Comment: I can say and confirmed that ```if nameID is None:``` was the solution for me and works like I wished! :) Thank you very much @Martijn